# 1 query or 2 separate queries?

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to get data from two exactly the same tables and print them?  Currently I am able to search in TABLE1 but not in TABLE2 as well.

EDITTED

```
$name= $_SESSION['NAME'];

USER 
ID - NAME
1 - AAAA
2 - BBBB
3 - CCCC
4 - DDDD
5 - EEEE

TABLE1
ID - CODE - BUYSELL
1 -A - Buying
2 - A - Buying
3 - B Buying
4 - B - Selling
5 - C - Selling

 "SELECT * from TABLE1, TABLE2, USER WHERE '$person' = USER.NAME 
    AND TABLE1.ID = USER.ID"; 

TABLE2
ID - CODE - YESNO - CAR
1 - A - YES - VOLVO
2 - B - YES - FORD
3 - C - YES - M
4 - D - NO - BMW
5 - A - NO - VOLVO

(AND TABLE2.ID = USER.ID?????)
```

I want all to search both tables 1 and 2? But adding `TABLE2.ID = USER.ID` is basically looking for the same values in both tables. So if I wanted CODEs for USERID 1 from table1 and 2.

Is it possible under 1 query or 2?

Comment: What is the output you are looking for? (And if both Table1 and Table2 have the user id as id column, why not add both tables to the users table?)

Comment: Why do you have 2 different tables with the similar data, at first?

Comment: @Arjan: because of normalization?

Comment: I have other columns that are different in the tables which I have not included, which I will eddit my post now Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) to combine the results of two queries into one:

```
(SELECT id, name AS value, "users" AS tbl_name FROM users WHERE ...)
UNION
(SELECT id, code AS value, "codes" AS tbl_name FROM codes WHERE ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you that USER.ID is the same as, and is a relevant connection to, TABLE1.ID and TABLE2.ID then I would suggest a JOIN.

```
SELECT *
FROM `user` AS a 
JOIN `table1` AS b 
JOIN `table2` AS c 
ON a.id = b.id || a.id = c.id
WHERE (a.name = '".$person."') 
GROUP BY a.id
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a [MySQL JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html).

```
SELECT USER.NAME, TABLE1.ID AS `T1ID`, TABLE2.ID AS `T2ID`
FROM USER 
LEFT JOIN TABLE1 ON TABLE1.ID=USER.ID
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE2.ID=USER.ID
```